# Where can I find my EUT tokens?

Tags: address.transfer

I've paid with my cb account to obtain during an ICO for EUT tokens. Looks like per etherscan that token were disbursed successfully, but not sure where I can go or wallet I can use to see my token balance and if I decide to sell the tokens in the future. Do I need to sign up for an ethereum based wallet in order to view my tokens? I have the token holder key and contract address who provided the tokens. Can someone assist?

Comment: Since you used your coinbase account you should ask them for support. If you have your private key, you can import into a wallet that support arbitrary tokens like Ethereum Wallet.